# How to generate a table in SQL having sequence numbers from 0 to a max value

Tags: mysql, sequence

I am currently using

```
SET @startnum = 0;
SET @endnum = 10;

WITH n AS (
SELECT @startnum AS num
UNION ALL
SELECT @startnum +1 FROM n WHERE @startnum < @endnum
)
SELECT num FROM n ORDER BY num;
```

But the version of SQL that I am using doesn't support "With table" query.
Also, I am not able to use `row_number()` or `rank_over()` partition by functions.

Comment: mySQL workbench 6.2
2008 version

Comment: Sure! Will update that..

Answer (score 0):

If I need such a table, I do the following:

```
create table t (int col1);
insert into t values (1);
create view v as select max(col1) as mcol1 from t;
```

and then as often as required:

```
insert into t
select col1 + mcol1
  from t, v
 where col1 + mcol1 <= NUMBEROFROWSDESIRED;
```

This will double your table on each execution

Comment: This step is effective, but I will have to execute the query manually, whereas the numberofrowsdesired is also an automated number. Is there any alternative method?

Comment: You could put it in a while loop, replacing NUMBEROFROWSDESIRED by a (shell) variable and iterating until the number of rows inserted is not a power of 2. (0 isn't a power of 2, hence if you need e.g. 16384 rows, you'll end up with an extra execution doing nothing).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about SQLYog but it looks like a MySQL tool, not SQL Server (this post was tagged with T-SQL). I also don't know much about MySQL but would suggest creating a permanent numbers table with as many numbers as you need then you can use it like this:

```
-- say I need the numbers 1 to 10:
SELECT N
FROM tally
WHERE N BETWEEN 1 AND 10; -- these can be variables
```

To create one you can use this syntax (which works in T-SQL or MYSql):

```
CREATE TABLE tally (N int NOT NULL,  PRIMARY KEY (N));
```

To populate it you can do so using a loop (I don't recommend loops but will make an exception here since no other syntax is working for you):

**T-SQL version:**

```
DECLARE @i int;
SET @i = 1;

-- T-SQL syntax
WHILE @i <= 1000 -- change this to the max number of rows that you want
BEGIN
  INSERT dbo.tally VALUES (@i);
  SET @i = @i+1;
END;
```

**MySQL Syntax:**

```
-- MySQL syntax
declare ii int unsigned default 1000;
declare i  int unsigned default 0;

truncate table foo;
start transaction;
while i < ii do
  insert into dbo.tally (N) values (i);
  set i=i+1;
end while;
commit;
```

Note: I can't test my MySQL query since I don't have access to a MySQL box at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

```
select (h*100+t*10+u+1) x from
(select 0 h union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union
select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) A,
(select 0 t union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union
select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) B,
(select 0 u union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union
select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) C
order by x;
```

This worked finally ! It seems pretty easy and straight forward and I can work with 1000 numbers as such.

In case there is a better way out there, please let me know.